# Return on a futures contract

Tags: stocks, futures, derivatives

If Sam invests $200000 on Futures and takes Futures short position on an index fund whose settlement is one year from now, with the current futures price being $1200.
The relation between spot price(S) and futures price(F) is given as : F = S * e^(r*T);
where r is the risk free rate = 10% and T is time to settlement.
The index fund currently priced at $1100.
If after six months the price is expected to be $1203.
What will be his profit/loss after 6 months?

Comment: d) All of the above

Comment: 1) find the future price at T using the formula provided. 2) calculate the different between the futures price and T and the price at T + 0.5. The difference is the P/L. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: @DStanley future price calculation with which spot price? Can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: "The index fund currently priced at $1100". Although I just realized that you have given both a spot and futures price that don't align exactly to the formula, so something else is wrong.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer as the number of purchased contracts and the FPV of the future is not stated.